# JavaScript redirect to another page in BlackBerry WebWorks

Tags: javascript, blackberry-webworks

I can't believe how difficult it is to do the simplest of things for BlackBerry. All I want to do is navigate to another local web page in my BlackBerry WebWorks app from a menu. Here's the code:

```
function clickMe1() {
    window.location = "what.html";
}
blackberry.ui.menu.clearMenuItems();
var item = new blackberry.ui.menu.MenuItem(false, 1, "What It Does", clickMe1);
blackberry.ui.menu.addMenuItem(item);
```

But Ripple complains: "The requested URL /ripple/what.html was not found on this server." WTF.

If I do this:

```
<a href="what.html">Click me.</a>
```

no problem finding what.html, so what gives???

Comment: Okay, I found a solution. It's stupid that I have to do this, but I guess that's how the BlackBerry WebWorks universe swings.
 
var loc = window.location;
window.location = loc.protocol + "//" + loc.host + "/MyApp/what.html";